# WordPress database custom order by post type

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post  type called requirement. I want to display requirement list in the front-end of site.

And this is my template file code for requirement list:

```
<div id="listing_loader">Loading...</div>
            <div id="listing_ajax_container"> 



            <?php
            wp_reset_query();
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            if(is_front_page()){
                 $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
            }

            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'requirement',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'paged'             => $paged,
                'posts_per_page'    => $prop_no,

                'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                'order'             => 'DESC',


            );
       //  print_r($args);
            add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 
            $prop_selection = new WP_Query($args);
            remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 
            $counter = 0;

            while ($prop_selection->have_posts()): $prop_selection->the_post(); 
                include(locate_template('req-listing.php'));
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();               
            ?>
            </div>
```

I am getting `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_value' in 'order clause']` error.

So how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When using custom WP_Query and you want to order the results by custom field `meta_value` you should note that a `meta_key=keyname` **must also be present** in the query.

For example:

`$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'requirement', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );`

Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect). Use `meta_value_num` instead for numeric values.

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for details.